# Preserve argument splitting when storing command with whitespaces in variable

Tags: bash

I'd like to store a command line in a variable, and then execute that command line. The problem is, the command line has arguments with spaces in them. If I do

```
$ x='command "complex argument"'
$ $x
```

it calls `command` with `"complex` and `argument"`. I tried using `"$x"` thinking it would preserve the argument splittings, but it only tries to execute a program with the file name `command "complex argument"`. I also tried variations of the quotes (`'` vs `"`) and using `exec`, but it didn't help. Any ideas?

Edit: `eval "$x"` *almost* works, but if the whitespaces *separating* arguments are newlines and not spaces, then it treats the lines as separate commands.
Edit2: The extra `"` quotes were too much, and made eval interpret the newlines not as spaces, but as command delimiters. The solutions in the answers all work.

---

For testing purposes, I define:

```
$ function args() { while [[ "$1" != "" ]]; do echo arg: $1; shift; done }
```

This works as expected:

```
$ args "1 2" 3
arg: 1 2
arg: 3

$ x="arg 4 5 6"
$ $x
arg: 4
arg: 5
arg: 6
```

This doesnt:

```
$ x="args \"3 4\" 5"
$ $x
arg: "3
arg: 4"
arg: 5
```

Answer (score 5):

A safe approach is to store your command line in a BASH array:

```
arr=( command "complex argument" )
```

Then execute it:

```
"${arr[@]}"
```

OR else another approach is to use BASH function:

```
cmdfunc() {
    command "complex argument" 
}

cmdfunc
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is

```
x='command "complex argument"'
eval $x
```